# Override Javascript in my app

Tags: javascript

I have one application using javascript function as bellow

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
            if ($ClickedOption) {
                $('i', $ClickedOption).removeAttr('class').addClass('fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin');
            }
        });
```

I don't want to change this file but i want to change

```
fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin 
to
fa fa-circle-o-notch
```

in my file, how can i do that?

I want to keep JS file with this function same but in one of my PHP file where i include this JS, i want to change this code

Thanks

Comment: You can't if you are not willing to change the original code. Note that it  could be changed to use a variable instead of hard coding the class name and that variable value can be changed within the app before the event occurs

Comment: Remove the class from the css file

Comment: If I understand correctly this code is used as a shared function? And what you want to do is to hold on this function for all pages but one? If this is your case you could just enter one more check in your code where you could see the url of the current page (probably with the window.location.href). If this is ok by you I can post it as an answer.